# NSString value to show in label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to show the Latitude and Longtitude value in this line in a label instead of NSLog :

> NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

Any tips on how to do it ?

Comment: please put in some level of research before asking questions like this. This is covered in hundreds of tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is first week Objective C stuff. You might want to do some reading before running to the forums  with your questions or you will quickly wear out the goodwill of those who are best able to help you.

If your label is called myLabel, you could use code like this:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
  @"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f", 
  newLocation.coordinate.latitude, 
  newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using story boards then you create an IBOutlet.  Then you change the text with something like:

```
self.mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```